# Unable to DataBind to ListView because of SelectMethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, routedata

I have a `ListView` and i use the `SelectMethod` of the `ListView` to populate it. I am looking to apply filters to the data returned from a `DropDownList`.  The problem that i am facing is i cannot `DataBind()` on this `ListView` because of the `SelectMethod` that is uses.

So figure i would change that and `DataBind()` the whole time instead of using the `SelectMethod`(Is that better?). Then the problem I face is my method was grabbing `[RouteData]`. Right now i am grabbing the `[RouteData]`as a param to my method. Please see below.

```
   public IQueryable<Product> GetProducts([RouteData] string categoryName, , [RouteData] string brandName, [RouteData] string subCatName)
{
       //Do stuff
}
```

below is the ListView

```
   <asp:ListView ID="productList" runat="server"
     DataKeyNames="ProductID"
     ItemType="E_Store_Template.Models.Product"
     SelectMethod="GetProducts">
       // do stuff 
</asp:ListView>
```

How can I use `DataBind()` and still grab the `[RouteData]` from URL? Or do i have to use QueryString to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to grab the route data by using the code below. This allowed me to grab that data and use Databind() instead of having to use the selectmethod to get this data.

```
Convert.ToString(Page.RouteData.Values["categoryName"]);



Convert.ToInt32(Page.RouteData.Values["scID"]);
```